# Jquery onClick but on Tab

Tags: jquery

This code works fine when the user clicks a field. I want it so that when they tab (press the alt key) or ANY key.. no matter what happens, if this field is active, run this jQuery code. So far I only know .click()

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fullname").click(function(){
        $("#note_email").fadeIn();
    });
});

<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" value="" /><div style="display:none" id="note_email">Your name is case sensitive</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [jQuery.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and bind all the events that should execute this code.

```
$("#fullname").bind('click keypress keyup change focus', function(){
    $("#note_email").fadeIn();
});
```

But it seems to me that focus would handle what you want

```
$("#fullname").bind('focus', function(){
    $("#note_email").fadeIn();
});
```

OR

```
$("#fullname").focus(function(){
    $("#note_email").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: How about if they are not on the form tab?

Comment: If they it is not called `unfocus`  it is called `blur`